# Lua scrip: mpv-cut. change location for cut videos

Tags: lua, windows-10, config, video-processing, mpv

While playing YouTube videos, the script saves the cut clips on the RAM rather than a C: directory, I believe.

What line should I add to the `config.lua` file?

I use [mpv-cut](https://github.com/familyfriendlymikey/mpv-cut), or there is another scrip that allows me to change the location within C:?

I chose this instead because it was easy to install. I'm don't write Lua code at all. I have windows 10, installed ffmpeg and yt-dlp.

Answer (score 0):

To move the file you can use cd and mkdir in your terminal as that's much easier than learning a lua api. mpv-cut saves it to its own folder so if you find the folder with cd, you can then use bash or powershell commands to move it around as you would like to.